# Valid Inequality Verification for MIP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am asked to use the mixed integer rounding procedure to show that
$$ x_2+x_4 \leq 20+4(y-2)$$
is a valid inequality for

X = {(x,y)$\in R_{+}^{4}* Z_{+}^{1}: x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \leq 10y , x_1\leq13,x_2\leq15,x_3\leq6,x_4\leq9$}

However, I don't know where to start giving the MIP rounding procedure depends mainly on integers, not real numbers.

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *simple rounding inequality* for $$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb Z : y - x \le \beta\}$$
turns the inequality $y - x \le \beta$ into $$y - \frac{x}{1 - (\beta - \lfloor \beta \rfloor)} \le \lfloor \beta \rfloor \tag{$\star$}$$ 
The idea is that $(\star)$ is the splitting inequality we get from knowing that either $y \le \lfloor \beta \rfloor$ or $y \ge \lfloor \beta \rfloor+1$: it cuts off the non-integer point $(0,\beta)$ by a half-plane defined by the points $(0, \lfloor \beta \rfloor)$ and $(1 - (\beta - \lfloor \beta \rfloor),\lfloor \beta \rfloor+1)$.

---

When applying $(\star)$ to other problems, our first goal is to put our constraints on $y, x_2, x_4$ into a form similar to $y  - x \le \beta$: we need a nonnegative real value to use as $x$.

We have two useful things we can say about $x_2 + x_4$: 
$$\begin{cases} x_2 + x_4 \le 10y \\
x_2 + x_4 \le 15 + 9 = 24
\end{cases}$$
So our nonnegative real variable can be $10y - x_2 - x_4$, and we can use that to write down the inequality $$10y - (10y - x_2 - x_4) \le 24 \implies y - (y - 0.1x_2 - 0.1x_4) \le 2.4$$
Applying $(\star)$ yields
$$y - \frac{y - 0.1x_2 - 0.1x_4}{0.6} \le 2 \implies x_2 + x_4 \le 12 + 4y$$
as desired.

Comment: Note: my formulation mostly matches [Integer Programming](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319110073) by Conforti, Cornuejols, and Zambelli, since it was the only reference I had on hand, so your approach to MIP rounding might be slightly different.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. superb explanation .. very clear to understand